# Why does maven-resources-plugin copy files multiple times (appfuse-basic-spring-archetype v2.1.0)

Tags: appfuse, maven-resources-plugin

When successfully running `>mvn package` on an appfuse-basic-spring-archetype v2.1.0 project, the console output displays:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ScanillionAppTier02 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
```

I direct your attention to the last 3 lines (Copying 16...). I ran `>mvn -X package` to get DEBUG output, which shows that the resources plugin claims to be first filtering the 16 files and then copying them twice.

Even more copies happen within the forked hibernate3-maven-plugin:hbm2ddl portion of the build; in that section, the output shows the 16 files being filtered once and copied 4 times.

Again, the build works, so I could have (should have?) counted my blessings, averted my eyes, and got on with my project. Alas, I went down this rat hole and it's going to bug me until I get an answer. Help a guy get some sleep. :-)

EDIT 3/19/2012 cdhabecker: more detail

In the maven output with the -X option, I found this:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) buildFilters = []
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) escapeWindowsPaths = true
[DEBUG]   (s) includeEmptyDirs = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (s) overwrite = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.foo:foo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\pom.xml
[LOOK]   (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: true, FileSet {directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\src\main\resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {ApplicationResources*.properties}]}}, 
[LOOK]                    Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: true, FileSet {directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\target\resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}, 
[LOOK]                    Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\target\resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}, 
[LOOK]                    Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\foo\target\resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@eddac
[DEBUG]   (f) supportMultiLineFiltering = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useBuildFilters = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useDefaultDelimiters = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

If you look at the lines marked [LOOK], you'll see that maven-resources thinks that it has 4 tasks (the filter of 20 files, the filter of 16 files, and the 2 redundant copies of those 16 files).

So now I suspect that something (e.g., native2ascii-maven-plugin or other plugins or the maven build plan generator) is registering those tasks with maven-resources-plugin and that nothing in the system is bothering to notice that some of those tasks are redundant.